# How to hide Doc Lib toolbar for "New, Upload, Sync, Share"

Tags: web-part, document-library, office-365, document-set, formatting

The goal is to create a Document Library of Document Sets. New Document Sets need auto & unique names, which isn't possible using "New" since it requires a manual filename. As a workaround to the limitation, there is a Site Workflow emulating the "New" action, which populates the auto-ID name.

I want to replace the whole toolbar "New, Upload, Sync, Share, More" with a single button to start the faux-new workflow. **Can this be done? How?**

Common answers to this question, and their limitations in this case:

- Restricting users permissions on the library
  *Users need full access to add & edit files*
- Using a web part with "No Toolbar"
  *Users need multiple selectable Views, which web parts don't support for some reason* **(or do they?)**
- Add JS to hide the toolbar client-side
  *No JSLink option on a standard Document Library view form* **(or is there?)**

Feeling pretty boxed in trying to get this working, so I'm open to architectural suggestions if it makes things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much of an answer, but it's better than no answer at all... here are two options.

### Architecture Change

This involves giving up one of the original requirements, making the user experience a bit rough. Since the workflow changes the Doc Set name, the URL of the page will "go bad" while the user is viewing their new Doc Set.

1. Users Create new Doc Sets the normal way
2. On Create, a List Workflow renames the Doc Lib

### Web Part Editing

Originally, there was no way to edit the Library View as a Web Part Page, which prevented using the "No Toolbar" option. Maybe some combination of having SharePoint Designer open? The "Edit Page" option re-appeared, and this solution is now possible. Reproduced here for future internet travelers.

1. Select Settings -> Edit Page (for some reason this wasn't available at first)

[image: O365 Settings > Edit Page]

2. Edit Web Part

[image: Edit Web Part]

3. Set Toolbar Type to No Toolbar

[image: Set to No Toolbar]